# Retrieve processing instructions using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document containing processing instructions. I know that, with the `XmlDocument` class, you can use

```
var node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')") as XmlProcessingInstruction;
```

but I want to use `XDocument`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I access an XML file's nodes with the `XDocument` class.
However, you'll have to be more specific on what you want to do with it.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("filepath");
var node = doc.Nodes().OfType<XElement>().SingleOrDefault(n => n.Name == "node name");
var node_value = node.Value;
var node_descendants = node.Descendants();
```

UPDATE:

As you may have noticed there's no **SelectSingleNode** in XDocument, in fact, to retrieve the node you want you'll have to fetch it from the corresponding ienumerable collection, or alternatively from the predefined **FirstNode**, **NextNode**, **PreviousNode**, **LastNode**, but you cannot apply any filters to those. Therefore the only ways to retrieve ProcessingInstruction nodes are

```
var pI_nodes = doc.Nodes().OfType<XProcessingInstruction>();
```

And

```
var pI_nodes = (from node in doc.Nodes()
                where node.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction
                select node);
```

If you expect to retrieve several **ProcessingInstructions** and need to filter these as well, the equivalent to the **node name** would the **Target** property

```
var filtered_pIs = pI_nodes_1.Where(pI => pI.Target == "xml-stylesheet");
```

And as a final reminder the value of the processing instruction is stored in the **Data** property.

```
string pI_value = filtered_pIs.First().Data
```

Comment: Hello, processing instructions are a special type of node that I do not believe will work with this code since they do not have node names.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
var node = xDoc.Root.Nodes().OfType<XProcessingInstruction>().First();
```

Comment: I think `xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')")` is equivalent to `xDoc.Nodes().OfType<XProcessingInstruction>().First()` as that selects the first processing instruction child node of the document node. Your attempt `xDoc.Root.Nodes().OfType<XProcessingInstruction>()` select all processing instruction child nodes of the root element.